# How to automatically indexing mysql database to solr

Tags: php, mysql, solr, amazon-ec2

I have installed the solr in EC2 instance which are working well. But now I need to indexing mysql database to solr using cronjob automatically. I tried some of way to do that using cron job.

Here the thing I tried

```
*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/html/cronjob && /var/www/html/cronjob/update-solr.sh
```

But this command give me pattern not found error in EC2 instance.

Here are my solr configuration

```
<dataConfig>


    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing" user="root" password="123"
                batchSize="1" />
    <document name="content">

        <entity name="mainsearch"
                query="select @curRow := @curRow + 1,a.* from ( select jb_title,Companyname,job_id from `jobs` 
 where jb_approve_status='1' AND
 jobs.is_deleted = '0'
 ) as a JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
">
            <field column="@curRow := @curRow + 1" name="uniqueid" />
            <field column="Companyname" name="COMPANY_NAME" />
            <field column="jb_title" name="JOB_TITLE" />
            <field column="job_id" name="id" />

        </entity>

    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Please check the screenshot where I manually click on execute button after the selecting entity mainsearch.
[image]

So tried using other solution provided in stackoverflow such as below

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://<solr_host>:8983/solr/<core_name>/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Above solution not indexing mainsearch entity data so how can I do indexing the entity = mainsearch data using cronjob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that any scripts should be prefixed by `#!/bin/bash` or similar to provide the interpreter - when executing it through cron, it won't have the existing shell to use for parsing. Does triggering dataimport work if you do it manually from the command line?

Comment: I am using this command
#!/bin/bash
wgetProgram=wget
urlCmd='http://45.454.54.45:8983/solr/#/talentscan/dataimport//dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false'
statusCmd='http://45.454.54.45:8983/solr/#/talentscan/dataimport//dataimport?command=status'
outputDir=.
$wgetProgram -O $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt ${statusCmd}
2>/dev/null
status=`fgrep idle $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt`
if [[ ${status} == idle ]]
then
     $wgetProgram -O $outputDir/status_update_index.txt ${urlCmd}
2>/dev/null
fi